# Filling Word tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi everyone I only started coding in VBA 3 days ago and I am currently struggling to fill a table that is already in the word doc I would not be able to create a new table as it's a company document. Im using two for loops to choose the right row and column but as a simple test I tried to put the same value in the cells however I nothing is getting filled. I was wondering if someone could help me with it?

```
For i = 1 To totalFlight
    For j = 1 To 7
     ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(k + 1, j + 1).Range.Text = batteryNo(k)
        
        
    Next j

Next i
```

Comment: Do you need to use I rather than k in your cell coordinates

Comment: Where is `k` defined? What is it?

Comment: After realising my stupidity I should not have been using k at all I apologise for the mistake